# [SOLVED] catkin_make hangs forever

Tags: catkin, ros-lunar, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<strike>ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS</strike>

ROS Lunar on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

catkin_make starts up and gets as far as BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on and then hangs.
There are no high cpu processes listed in top, and no output to dmesg at all.

What else can I check to investigate why it hangs?

Edit:

A clean install of Lunar worked fine until today.

**ps aux | grep cmake**

```
automat+  1996  0.0  0.3 153344 14328 pts/17   S+   15:16   0:00 cmake /home/automation/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/automation/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/automation/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles
automat+  2078  0.1  0.4 276192 16644 pts/17   S+   15:16   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/empy --raw-errors -F /home/automation/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.py -o /home/automation/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em
automat+  2114  0.0  0.3  57160 14012 pts/17   S+   15:16   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/empy --raw-errors -F /home/automation/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.py -o /home/automation/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em
automat+  2115  0.0  0.3  56872 13940 pts/17   S+   15:16   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/empy --raw-errors -F /home/automation/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.py -o /home/automation/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake /opt/ros/lunar/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em
automat+  2390  0.0  0.0  21292   988 pts/1    S+   15:28   0:00 grep --color=auto cmake
```

`env | grep -i ros | sort` (in an auto-sourced terminal)

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/automation/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/lunar
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/automation/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/lunar/lib
PATH=/home/automation/bin:/home/automation/.local/bin:/opt/ros/lunar/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/lunar/lib/pkgconfig
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
ROS_DISTRO=lunar
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/lunar/etc/ros
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/automation/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/automation/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/lunar/share
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/lunar/share/ros
```

Edit 10/19/17:
`apt-cache policy python-empy`

```
python-empy:
Installed: 3.3.2-1build1
Candidate: 3.3.2-1build1
Version table:
*** 3.3.2-1build1 500
500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`pip list | grep empy`

```
empy (3.3.2)
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
automation@atc-nuc-ros:~$ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 470kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272797/%5Bsolved%5D-catkin_make-hangs-forever/) by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2017-10-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
Delete `build` and `devel`, and try running things as follows:

```
catkin_make VERBOSE=1
```

If things hang, see what it was doing.

Seeing the `order_package.py` in that `ps` output: how many packages do you have, and what sort of machine is this?

**Comment by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on 2017-10-18**:
Verbose output: https://pastebin.com/DiDiuGfZ  Still hangs after BUILD_SHARE_LIBS is on.

We have one package with 8 nodes. This machine is an Intel NUC, we previously used a Surface Pro 3 that worked flawlessly for the past year or more, then recently stopped working.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
Does `catkin_tools` work? That is not a solution, but just trying to get some more info.

**Comment by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on 2017-10-18**:
catkin_tools: command not found

Is it a command I should be running? Do I need to have something else installed first? I did the ros-lunar-desktop-full install.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
[catkin-tools.readthedocs.io](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

**Comment by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on 2017-10-18**:
`catkin build` just ran for an hour and didn't get anywhere...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
Let's take a step back: can you build an empty workspace (with `catkin_make` or `catkin build`, I don't care). So:

1. open a new terminal (no auto sourcing anything)
2. `source /opt/ros/$distro/setup.bash`
3. `mkdir -p /tmp/empty_ws/src`
4. `cd /tmp/empty_ws`
5. `catkin_make`

**Comment by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on 2017-10-18**:
I followed your instructions exactly and it behaves the same as before. Hangs after BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on :(

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it! We are definitely at our wit's end with this thing and none of the similar issues we found online had a working solution.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
Can you add the output of `env | grep -i ros | sort` to your original question? Just edit it using the *edit* button/link.

**Comment by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on 2017-10-18**:
Edited question to add information.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
And just making sure: in the non-auto-sourced terminal it hangs as well when trying to build the empty workspace? Have you installed any Python packages between when it worked and when it stopped working?

I ask because in your `ps` output I see it hanging on `empy` invocations.

**Comment by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on 2017-10-18**:
Yes, in the non-auto-sourced terminal it hangs building an empty workspace. I don't think there are any new python packages since it was working.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-19**:
Can you show the output of `apt-cache policy python-empy` and of `pip list | grep empy`?

Stabbing in the dark here, but again, seeing `empy` hang like that seems to point to something.

**Comment by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) on 2017-10-19**:
Didn't have pip so I installed it. Added outputs to question above.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-19**:
Must say this is hard to diagnose without direct access to the machine involved.

Perhaps @William has some ideas?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-10-19**:
Can you run `cmake` directly on your package? Something like `cd path/to/package; mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a single package in our system that did not adhere to the naming conventions (package name contains capital letters). Catkin threw a warning and then hung on build until the package was removed/renamed.

It wasn't obvious that it was a fatal error considering the message was prefixed with "Warning" and not "Error".

---

Originally posted by [DHCustomPak](https://answers.ros.org/users/11691/dhcustompak/) with karma: 70 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-10**:
Thanks for reporting back.

Not adhering to naming conventions should definitely not be a fatal error or cause Catkin to hang.

If you can create an MWE and report it [here](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues) that would be great.